# How to use variable declared within a php file, inside another file that included

Tags: php, laravel, variables, include

this is my problem.
file1: logged in users

```
    <?php
//this file is to save and reuse logged in user info's in dashboard pages.
//  General
$CurrentUser = Auth::user();
$Role = $CurrentUser->role()->value('RoleName');
$CurrentUser->Mode = 'ON';
$CurrentUser->save();
$UserFullName = $CurrentUser->FirstName . ' ' . $CurrentUser->LastName;
$UserStatus = $CurrentUser->Status;
$UserMode = $CurrentUser->Mode;
$Menus = MenuPicker($CurrentUser);

// for admin badges
$allNewRegisteredOrders = AllNewRegisteredOrders();
$employmentRequest = NewEmployment();
$OnlineUsers = OnlineUsers();
$SiteVisitors = GetSiteVisitors(1);

//  for customer badges
$CustomerRegisteredOrders = CustomerRegisteredOrders($CurrentUser->id);
$CustomerInvoices = CustomerInvoices($CurrentUser->id);
```

file 2: dashboard

```
@extends('auth.DashboardLayout.DashboardMasterLayout')
@section('content')
@include('script.DashboardLoggedInUser')

    @switch($CurrentUser->role()->value('id'))
        {{--=============================== ِ Admin =======================================--}}
        @case(1)
            @section('Title',$Role)
            @include('DashboardAdminIndex')
        @break
```

this is a part of my code, but cant use that `$CurrentUser`in dashboard.
any idea will be appreciated
thanks.

Comment: "inside another file that included" <- where is it included?

Comment: Grab yourself a coffee and read the Laravel documentation  and learn about the MVC pattern. Then my friend, you will see that your question will be answered automatically.